# joi: Custom errors are not returned, abortEarly is set to false

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I can't get this joi validation to return all the errors just like what it does with default errors.

So here I'm setting individual custom errors for each field:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.string().error(new Error('must be string')), 
    b: Joi.number().error(new Error('must be number'))
});
```

Then when validating with abortEarly set to false, it only returns the first error it will encounter.

```
Joi.validate({a: 1, b: false}, schema, {abortEarly: false})
```

The error returned is like this,

```
{ error: [Error: must be string], value: { a: 1, b: false }}
```

when it should be returning all the errors in some manner.

Am I using abortEarly incorrectly or is there a process needed to be done in returning all custom errors? Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I found the answer. My joi library wasn't updated so I had it rolled up to 10.4.1 from 10.2.x. There was some features that I've seen in the documentation that didn't work when I tried it in the older version, including the solution I did.

I tried using this pattern and it works:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.string().error(() => 'must be string'), 
    b: Joi.number().error(() => 'must be number')
});
```

Like so:

```
{ [ValidationError: child "a" fails because [must be string]. child "b" fails because [must be number]]
  isJoi: true,
  name: 'ValidationError',
  details: 
   [ { message: '"a" must be a string',
       path: 'a',
       type: 'string.base',
       context: [Object] },
     { message: '"b" must be a number',
       path: 'b',
       type: 'number.base',
       context: [Object] } ],
  _object: { a: 1, b: false },
  annotate: [Function] }
```

Then I'll just parse the error.message to get all the error messages and process it.

```
'child "a" fails because [must be string]. child "b" fails because [must be number]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to check each validation errors as well.
If you have one validation, it doesn't matter what condition would be, you can do like this :

```
username: Joi.string() // It has to be string
  .label("Username") // The label
  .error(new Error('It is whatever error')) // Custom general error
```

You can do this with arrow function too :

```
username: Joi.string() // It has to be string
  .label("Username") // The label
  .error(() => 'It is whatever error') // Custom general error
```

But If there are some validation params and errors we have these solutions :

```
password: Joi.string()  // It has to be string
  .min(8) // It has to have at least 8 characters
  .required() // It has to have a value
  .label("Password") // The label
  .error(errors => {
    return errors.map(err => { // Here we map the errors (ES6) discover within an array
       if (err.type === "string.min") { // Check the type of error e.g: 'string.min,any.empty,number.min,...'
         return { message: "The length of the parameter should be more than 8 characters" }; // Which message we want to display
       } else {
         return { message: "another validation error" };
       }
    });
  })
```

There is another solution with Switch Case :

```
password: Joi.string()  // It has to be string
  .min(8) // It has to have at least 8 characters
  .required() // It has to have a value
  .label("Password") // The label
  .error(errors => {
    return errors.map(err => { // Here we map the errors (ES6) discover within an array
     switch (err.type) {
       case "string.min":
          return { message: "The length of the parameter should be more than 8 characters" }; // Which message we want to display
       case "any.empty":
          return { message: "The parameter should have a value" };
     }
  });
})
```

> Please noticed that if one of the validation errors did not specify you have error that **err.type** is undefined.

you can use **err.context** within the message to display the label, limit, max , ... in dynamic :

```
message: `${err.context.label} must have at least ${err.context.limit} characters.`
```

refrence : [Joi Document](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyerrorerr)